# MySQL on the problem of slowing down the efficiency of View calling Function

Tags: mysql, database, function, view, procedure

I will explain the problem as follows:

(1) Database version: MySQL 8.0.23

(2) Data Sheet Name: TB_202104
This data table is used to store data from 2021-04-01 00:00:00 to 2021-04-30 23:59:59. There are 99200872 data
The data table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TB_202104 (
    OID INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ChannelOID INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Value DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    LastUpdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (OID,Timestamp) USING BTREE,
    INDEX IDX_ChaOID(ChannelOID) USING BTREE,
    INDEX IDX_ChaOID_Timsta(ChannelOID, Timestamp) USING BTREE,
    INDEX IDX_Timsta (Timestamp) USING BTREE
    )
    COMMENT='Save 2021/04 sensor data'
    COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
    PARTITION BY RANGE (unix_timestamp(`Timestamp`))
    (PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1617840000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1618444800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1619049600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (1619827200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION pMax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB
    );
```

(3) Function name: GetMyStartDateTime
Function structure is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetMyStartDateTime()
    RETURNS timestamp
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'Get custom start date and time'
    BEGIN 

    RETURN '2021-05-01 00:00:00';

    END
```

The purpose of this View table is to call GetMyStartDateTime() to filter the date and time data in the Timestamp field
The View table structure is as follows:

(4) View table name: DynamicTB

```
ALTER ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `DynamicTB ` 
    AS 
    select ChannelOID AS ChannelOID,
           Timestamp AS Timestamp,
           Value AS VALUE 
         
    from TB_202104 
    where (Timestamp >= GetMyStartDateTime()) 
    limit 1 ;
```

(5) When I execute the following instructions, the execution time becomes abnormally long, and the execution is not completed

```
SELECT * FROM DynamicTB
```

The problem is that the TB_202104 data table searched in the View table of DynamicTB has no data at 2021-05-01 00:00:00 at all.

(6) But if I first put DynamicTB as follows:

```
ALTER ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `DynamicTB ` 
    AS 
    select ChannelOID AS ChannelOID,
           Timestamp AS Timestamp,
           Value AS VALUE 
         
    from TB_202104 where (Timestamp >= '2021-05-01 00:00:00') 
    limit 1 ;
```

Then execute:

```
SELECT * FROM DynamicTB
```

The execution was completed in less than one second, because TB_202104 has no time data starting and after 2021-05-01 00:00:00.

(7) At present, the problem is that in the View table of DynamicTB, as long as the function called GetMyStartDateTime() is called,
it will become abnormally slow, or even impossible to complete at all.

GetMyStartDateTime() just returns the value of 2021-05-01 00:00:00, why call GetMyStartDateTime() in the View table of DynamicTB to get the same value
Is there a problem with execution exception?

Thanks For Your reply。

Comment: That's about 40 inserts per second.  Is there any chance that two entries for the same OID come in in the same second?

Answer (score 0):

A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is asking for trouble.  The engine is free to give you any row it likes.  Add `ORDER BY Timestamp` just before `LIMIT 1`.

Change the function to `DETERMINISTIC`; this might prevent the query from doing a table scan.